# Solar panel + USB

Tags: circuit-design

I am designing a circuit that will charge a 3.7V battery using a typical USB phone charger (5V/2A) in parallel with an embedded solar panel (6V/0.25A)

The charger IC has a minimum input voltage of 4.65V, therefore, I want to have as much voltage as possible arriving at that pin, so I want to avoid putting diodes on the input power lines.

My understanding is the following, when both power sources are connected, and the charger is asking for 2A, the dominating voltage at the line will be 5V because the charger can supply 8 times the amount of current compared to the solar panel. And because of the silicon in the solar panel, the element itself is a diode so the panel will always act as a current source and not current sink. Since the USB charger is the source then current will not flow from the solar panel to the charger, hence, no diode is needed.

More info about the project here: https://developpa.io/solar-mobile-charger/

I tried simulating this in LTSpice but it is not quite working, seems like the voltages collapse (I am probably doing something wrong):

[image]

Could you please validate my design?

Thank you

Comment: `charger is asking for 2A` ... that is incorrect ..... the charger can supply up to 2A

Comment: `voltages collapse` ... caused by using a current source as a load, which acts as a short circuit in the effort to draw 2A

Comment: You have a current divider, together with a voltage divider. If you break up the circuit by using external resistances instead of parasitic (which are the suggested way when you want things simplified, not explained), you'll probably have a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you but these replies do not address my question, only say that the simulation is wrong which I know already. I am interested in knowing if I will need the diodes or not